# Issue when embedding image in email body with PHPMailer

Tags: php, phpmailer, html-email

I want to generate a QR code using the [phpqrcode](http://phpqrcode.sourceforge.net/) library and send it as an image embedded in the email body (without attaching it to the email). I am using the [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) library to create and send the email.

The code I am using is as follows

```
<?php
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

include ('../phpqrcode/qrlib.php');
ob_start();
QRcode::png('TextToGenerateTheQRCodeFrom');
$imageString = base64_encode( ob_get_contents() );
ob_end_clean();

$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->setFrom( 'testqrsend@testqrsend.sdf', 'Test QR sender');
$mail->addAddress('xxxxxxxxxxx', 'John Doe');
$mail->Subject  = 'QR code';
$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->addStringEmbeddedImage($imageString,'qrcode');

$mail->Body = "<p> Your QR code </p><img src=\"cid:qrcode\" />";

if(!$mail->send()) {
  echo 'Message was not sent.';
  echo 'Mailer error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
  echo 'Message has been sent.';
}
?>
```

This is the email I receive.

[image].

As you can see, the image is not embedded within the email body. However there is a file attached. That file is a text file and contains the base64 value of the image.

What am I doing wrong and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: I believe that addStringEmbeddedImage expects the raw image and not the base64 encoded version. Have a go with this and see if it works.

Comment: @Chris, I passed the raw image as the first argument of addStringEmbeddedImage and checked. However, the image was still not displayed in the email body

Comment: @Chris, When you said pass the raw image to the addStringEmbeddedImage funtion, what I did was to assign the value returned by QRcode::png() to a variable as $img = QRcode::png('TextToGenerateTheQRCodeFrom'); and then passed $img as the first argument of addStringEmbeddedImage(). Is this what you meant? I am asking this now because when I read your comment again I do not feel that I did it right

Answer (score 1):

I have set something up myself and can confirm this this code works. I've sent an email to my Gmail account. I'll include a screenshot as proof ;-)

```
<?php

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$image = 'http://cdnqrcgde.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/jpeg.jpg';
$image = file_get_contents($image);

$body = '<p>this is a <strong>test</strong> email</p><p><img src="cid:qrcode" /></p>';

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
try {
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->Host = 'localhost';
    $mail->SMTPAuth = false;

    $mail->setFrom('chris@me.com', 'Chris');
    $mail->addAddress('me@gmail.com');

    $mail->isHTML(true);
    $mail->Subject = 'This is a PHPMailer Test';
    $mail->Body    = $body;
    $mail->AltBody = $body;

    $mail->addStringEmbeddedImage($image,'qrcode','qrcode.jpg');

    $mail->send();
    echo 'Message has been sent';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
```

[image]

Comment: I received the email as shown in your screenshot when I executed this code. Therefore I think the problem occurs when passing the generated QR code to be attached in the email

Comment: If you're still stuck and need a quick solution then you could always use Google to generate the QR code - https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=300x300&cht=qr&chl=hello&choe=UTF-8 - you could then change the value of hello to be the code to be displayed. You can then adjust my code to fetch the QR code from Google.

Comment: Chris - could you explain what $mail->AltBody = $body does? From the documentation it is for email clients who can't do HTML so since your $body has html elements in it does it somehow magically strip all the html and just leave the text parts? I need to send text messages via emails like 1234567890@vzwpix.com that can't do html so can add my $html_body to AltBody and it will take care of it?

Comment: Lazy example from me. I tend to send HTML to "Body" and then a plain text version of the first few paragraphs as "AltBody"

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you read [the documentation on the function you're using](http://phpmailer.github.io/PHPMailer/classes/PHPMailer.PHPMailer.PHPMailer.html#method_addStringEmbeddedImage). This is linked from the readme, also on the project page on github.

The reason this is if not working is that you're passing it some binary data without telling it what kind of thing it is, so it falls back to a generic `application/octet-stream` MIME type, which will appear as a generic attachment, as you're seeing.

Chris' example works because he also supplied a filename containing an extension, and PHPMailer uses that to derive a MIME type (if it can) if you don't provide an explicit MIME type in the call to `addStringEmbeddedImage`.

In short, change your call to this:

```
$mail->addStringEmbeddedImage($imageString, 'qrcode', 'qrcode.png');
```

Comment: when I make the change that you suggested, I get the email without the attachment. However the image is not displayed in the email body

Comment: Check its return value, show us your MIME structure. Be absolutely sure (_check_, don't assume it's right!) that the content is actually what you expect *before* you try to email it - using `file_get_contents` to fetch external URLs has quite a few limitations, especially if you use the default stream context.

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
$imgSrc = str_replace('amp;','', 'https://chart.googleapis.com/chart? 
cht=qr&chs=250x250&choe=UTF-8');    

$mail->setFrom('chris@me.com', 'Chris');
$mail->addAddress('me@gmail.com');

$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->Subject = 'This is a PHPMailer Test';
$mail->msgHTML("<p>this is a <strong>test</strong> email</p><img src='$imgSrc'>");
if(!$mail->send()){
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}else{
    echo "Message sent!";
}
```